# Spoof sender through Gmail SMTP in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, smtp

Gmail allows its users to send emails as though from another email address, as long as that address has been verified. Is doing so possible through Thunderbird and the Gmail SMTP servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as the e-mail address is verified in your Gmail account and you can send messages from it using Gmail's regular web interface.

Just add a new email account to Thunderbird with the appropriate name and e-mail address and configure it to use `smtp.gmail.com` with your usual credentials.

This can be in a new Profile, or an additional Identity in the same Profile.

> #### Using Identities
>
> When you configure an account, Thunderbird creates a default "identity" for the account that contains information like your name, your email address, the location where your messages should be stored, signature, etc. You can manually create additional identities for your account (via `Tools > Account Settings…`, **Manage Identities**). When you create (or reply) to a message, you can specify any of the identities you have configured by selecting it from the **From** drop-down list.
>
> Read more: [Home / Thunderbird / Using Identities](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-identities)

##### Create a New Identity:

1. In Thunderbird, click `Tools > Account Settings…`
2. Select the desired account from the list on the left, then click the **<kbd>Manage Identities</kbd>** button in the bottom right.
3. Click **<kbd>Add</kbd>**
4. In the the identity dialog, you'll specify:

   - **Settings:** name, address, signature, etc
   - **Copies & Folders:** cc, bcc, and where to store messages
   - **Composition & Addressing:** text format, quote management, signature, etc
   - **Security:** digital signatures and encryption

     <sup>Source: [Thunderbird Support, Using Identities](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-identities)</sup>